# HUF Account India

Tags: india, banking, bank-account

We have a HUF (Hindu Undivided Family) account in a Govt Bank. My father is "Karta" of this account and me being his son is also a member.

So, can I ask my employer (from part time job) to electronically transfer my money in this account? If he agrees and asks for account details, should I be providing details as:

1. Name in account - My Name (not Father's)
2. Bank's NEFT Details
3. HUF Account number

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to do it for the sake of saving tax, it won't help. The amount will still be treated as your income.

If it is consultation work you are doing, you may consider filing your taxes under 44ADA which would consider 50% of your income as expense.

Comment: Thanks, but I am still confused. For readers help also, can you please explain. `1.` Can I take it in HUF by providing details as I listed in question?`2.` Why it would my income and not HUF's income? `3.` How can I legally make it HUF's income? `4.` Do you mean to file 2 ITRs one as "ITR1" other as "44ADA"?